# Crash on reading file on seekg()

Tags: c++, ifstream, file-handling

I am trying to read a bmp file into a character buffer and transfer it across processes using inter process communication. I accomplished this using following code:

```
     std::ifstream ImageFile;
     char* str=new char[strlen(pFilePath)+strlen(pFileName)+1];
     strcpy(str,pFilePath);
     strcat(str,pFileName);
     ImageFile.open(str, ios::binary); 
     if(ImageFile.is_open()){
         ImageFile.seekg(0,ios::end);
         m_uiImageSize = ImageFile.tellg();
         ImageFile.seekg(0,ios::beg);

         m_pcImageBuffer = new char[m_uiImageSize];
         ImageFile.read(m_pcImageBuffer,m_uiImageSize);
         ImageFile.close();
     }

     WebCore::FloatRect rect;
     BITMAP cBitmap;
     HBITMAP hBitmap;
     tagBITMAPFILEHEADER bfh = *(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER*)m_pcImageBuffer;
     tagBITMAPINFOHEADER bih = *(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER*)(m_pcImageBuffer+sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER));
     RGBQUAD             rgb = *(RGBQUAD*)(m_pcImageBuffer+sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER)+sizeof(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER));

     BITMAPINFO bi;
     bi.bmiColors[0] = rgb;
     bi.bmiHeader = bih;

     char* pPixels = (m_pcImageBuffer+bfh.bfOffBits);
     char* ppvBits;
     hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(NULL, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**) &ppvBits, NULL, 0);
     SetDIBits(NULL, hBitmap, 0, bih.biHeight, pPixels, &bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
     GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &cBitmap);
```

This was working perfectly for me before. But now my program crashes at     ImageFile.seekg(0,ios::end) and I cant figure out why. The file opens fine and even the     ifstream::good() returns true. Following is my call stack:

```
StorageTree.exe!std::use_facet >(const std::locale & _Loc) Line 586 C++
    msvcp110d.dll!std::basic_istream >::_Sentry_base::_Sentry_base(std::basic_istream > & _Istr) Line 103   C++
    msvcp110d.dll!std::basic_istream >::sentry::sentry(std::basic_istream > & _Istr, bool _Noskip) Line 123 C++
    msvcp110d.dll!std::basic_istream >::seekg(__int64 _Off, int _Way) Line 876  C++
```

Pls guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. There wasn't any problem in the code, I had added some more code to the app and hadn't initialised some of my variables thus affecting the entry points and data locations.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I am running into this same problem, with seekg() or getline() or anything causing an 'access violation'.  and the file is open and valid.